# Visual Studio Code does not show outline for PowerShell Classes

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have created some Powershell Classes. They look like this:

```
Class UISwitcher {

    [NotesClientSwitcher]$ncs
    $objForm
    $objMessagebox
    [PSCustomObject]$objVersion
    [PSCustomObject]$objInstance
    [PSCustomObject]$objData
    $OKButton


    # Default constructor
    UISwitcher() {
       $this.ncs = New-Object -TypeName NotesClientSwitcher
    }   

    [void]StartSwitcher() {
       $this.ncs.GetAvailableDirectories()
       $this.CreateWindow()
       $this.CreateObjects()
       $this.ValidateForm()
       $this.ShowWindow()
    }

}
```

I try to edit them in Visual Studio Code 1.52.1 (user setup) and it works (autocomplete and everything). BUT: The outline view only shows the functions in that file and NOT the classes and their methods... this makes navigation quite cumbersome.

Are there any tricks or settings to make Visual Studio Code recognize classes in Powershell?

The setting "Features - Explorer - Outline: Show Classes" is enabled, just in case you wonder...

Comment: So, this is not a PowerShell code issue, but a development tool feature question. Sooo... ??? If you feel VSC should do this and you cannot find a setting (I did check a few extensions and they do not correct this limitation either), then that is a feature request. Submit the request to the VSCode and/or PowerShell team and see if it gets enough upvotes to get it added.